# Design of a system where results from a separate worker process need to be sent back to the correct producer thread

Tags: multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing, system-design

I'm designing a system where an HTTP service with multiple threads accepts request to perform work. These requests are placed into a multiprocessing queue and sent downstream to a worker process where the work is performed (let's assume that we have a reasonable expectation that work can be handled quickly and the HTTP threads aren't blocking for a long time)

The issue that I can't figure out how to solve is - once the worker process is done processing the request, how are the results returned to the specific producer that produced a request?

I considered having another multiprocessing queue - a "results" queue - that each producer has a handle to, and they can wait on this queue for the results. The issue is that there's no guarantee that a specific producer will pull the results for *their* request from this queue, it might go to some other producer, and that other producer won't hold the open connection to the requesting HTTP client so it won't be able to do anything with the results.

I've included a simple system diagram below that shows the producer threads and worker process
[image]

One solution here would be to have the worker process write the results to some data store, e.g. Redis, under a random key created by the producer, and the producer could watch this key for the result. However, I would prefer to avoid adding an external storage system if possible as the overhead of serializing to/from Redis would be non-trivial in some cases.

I don't think the language should matter here, but in case it does, this would be developed in Python using some standard microframework (like FastAPI)

EDIT - I thought of one possible solution. I can have another thread in the producer process that is responsible for reading from a "response" multiprocessing queue from the worker process. All other producer threads can then query some thread-safe data structure within this "response reader" thread for their specific results (which will be placed under some unique key generated by the producer)

The main issue I'm struggling with now is how to scale this to multiple producer processes (each with multiple producer threads) and multiple worker processes that are distinct (worker A handles different jobs from worker B)

Comment: You can use the actor model, where the actors are the workers, and the producer sends the work asynchronously to the actors: https://pykka.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#plain-actor

Comment: Its possible that a work queue is the wrong model here, since the producers are always waiting for a response.  What might be more appropriate is if the producer makes an asynchronous RPC request to a load balancer (rather than a queue) which selects an available worker to handle the request.  Then, the producer simply listens for a response on its socket (be it RPC or HTTP or whatever)